# How do I set a state to a value in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

There is a button that toggles dark and light mode, and the state of what mode the page is on is saved in `localStorage`. However, I cannot change the initial value of the state (`dark`) and I don't know why. This is done in a `useEffect` function but no matter what the value of `dark` is, it is always set to its initial value of `false`.

How do I set the value of the `localStorage` to the `dark` state?

```
function Mode() {
    const [dark, setDark] = useState(false);

    // localStorage.removeItem("dark");

    const onClick = () => {
        if (dark) {
            setDark(false);
            document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("dark");
        } else {
            setDark(true);
            document.querySelector("body").classList.add("dark");
        }
        localStorage.setItem("dark", dark);
    };

    const localDark = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dark"));

    useEffect(() => {
        if (localDark !== null) {
            setDark(!JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dark"))); // this is what does not change the value of dark
            onClick();
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <div onClick={onClick} className="mode">
            {dark ? <Light /> : <Dark />}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly use the value from `localStorage` in `useState` as the default. `useEffect` is unnecessary here.

```js
const [dark, setDark] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dark")));
document.body.classList.toggle('dark', dark);
```

The click event handler should set the `localStorage` dark value to the logical complement of the current value.

```js
const onClick = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("dark", !dark);
    setDark(!dark);
};
```

Comment: I also added an if statement that added or removed the `dark` class to the body after setting the useState

Comment: @tices `document.body.classList.toggle('dark', dark);` is sufficient (like shown in my answer). You don't need an if statement.

Comment: This only happens if the button is click but not when the page loads so I had to add it outside of the `onClick` function so that the page also changes mode to match the `dark` state

Comment: @tices I had edited my answer to put that under `setState` 29 mins ago. That was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Use a function to initialize the state from local storage. Update the storage and the body's class on init, and when `dark` state changes:

```
const getLocalDark = () => !!JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dark"));

function Mode() {
  const [dark, setDark] = useState(getLocalDark);

  const onClick = () => {
    setDark(d => !d);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const classList = document.querySelector("body").classList;
    
    if (dark) classList.add("dark");
    else classList.remove("dark");
    
    localStorage.setItem("dark", dark);
  }, [dark]);

  return (
      <div onClick={onClick} className="mode">
          {dark ? <Light /> : <Dark />}
      </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd be interested in a `useLocalStorage` hook. Here's how that can be implemented:

```
export const useLocalStorage = (key, initialState) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
        // Initialize with the value in localStorage if it
        // already exists there.
        const data = localStorage.getItem(key);

        // Otherwise, initialize using the provided initial state.
        return data ? JSON.parse(data) : initialState;
    });

    // Each time "value" is changed using "setValue", update the
    // value in localStorage to reflect these changes.
    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }, [value]);

    return [value, setValue];
};
```

This hook syncs the value seen in `localStorage` with the value stored in memory under the `value` variable.

The usage looks like this (almost identical to regular `useState`):

```
export const Counter = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useLocalStorage('count', 0);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{count}</p>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    setCount((prev) => prev + 1);
                }}>
                Increase count
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

However, the main caveat of this hook is that it's only really meant to be used in one component. That means, if you change the value from `light` to `dark` in one component using this hook, any other components using it won't be updated. So instead, you should look into using a similar implementation of what is demonstrated above, but using the [React **Context** API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). That way, you'll ensure your in-memory values are in sync with those stored in `localStorage`. Theming is one of the main uses of the Context API.

Good luck! :)